# Append to YCM dictionary in Vim

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I'm trying to append an entry to the dictionary `g:ycm_filetype_blacklist`. I would like to disable YouCompleteMe for Tex files, so I try adding the following line at the end of my vimrc:

```
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist.tex = 1
```

At startup, Vim will complaint that the variable is not defined, but it is available afterwards, and it contains the expected default entries.

I'm using Vim 8.0.

How can I append an entry to this dictionary on startup without defining it from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim YouCompleteMe enable .tex filetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648238/vim-youcompleteme-enable-tex-filetype)